# How to have `ll` command not display hidden files

Tags: command-line

When I type `ll` or `ls` to list the contents of a directory...

The `ls` command shows un-hidden files and folders in a horizontal view.
To show the hidden folders, I have to type `ls -a`. I like how this works.

The `ll` command shows all files and folders, including hidden ones without needing to add `-a`.

I would like `ll` to list only unhidden files and folders by default. And if I want to show the hidden ones, I'd like to have to type `ll -a`. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the file `.bashrc` in your home directory. The should be an entry which looks like:

```
alias ll='ls -la'
```

Remove the last `a`, save the file and open a new shell. Now `ll` should work as want you. If you do not find the line, you can add it to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

Comment: Also note worthy, I had to logout and log in before these changes took effect or at least start a new terminal session.

Comment: Yes, you can also type `. .bashrc` or, alternatively, `source .bashrc` to make the terminal reread the settings in the file .bashrc without exiting from the terminal.

Comment: Hi, logged as root in my $HOME/.bashrc I can see that alias, but still not working. I reloged and rebooted the server but... nothing. Any other clue? ty so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Technically **`ll`** is not a command on its own *but* an alias setup for slightly longer commands; by default it is set to `ls -l`.

For instance on your case, you can set `ll` to `ls -l` with

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

to your `.bashrc file`.

You can also use **`alias`** to add some time-saving commands. For instance, if you often update from the terminal you can assign a shortcut string to the command `apt-get update and apt-get upgrade` with:

```
alias up='apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'
```

Now you can just type `up` to save time.

Answer (score -2):

Add these lines:

```
# Custom aliases
alias l='ls -a'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -la'
```

to the end of `~/.bashrc`, for example using:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Comment: the alias is already defined - seems a waste of resources to define it again instead of editing the definition, as the other answers suggest. Also, you are changing two aliases not mentioned in the question for some reason...